# SUMIF date in column B is less than date in column C

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a list of values in Column A and want to sum these values where the date in Column B is less than Column C.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gBPq.png)
[image: Example]

In this example the correct value would be `2100`.

I have previously had to complete this task with reference to a single date (e.g. the date contained in C3) and used the formula:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B11,"<="&C3,A2:A11)
```

However in this instance I need each date in B to be less than or equal to the date in C. I have tried:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B11,"<="&C2:C11,A2:A11)
```

But I get a value of `0`. Any ideas?

Comment: either a) in column D add a calculation that works out the difference and therefore whether the row should be included (like `=C2-B2`, dragged down) then the calc is simply `=SUMIFS(A2:A11,D2:D11,">0")`, or b) use an array formula entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter like `=SUM(IF(B2:B11<C2:C11,A2:A11,0))`

Comment: The worksheet I need to use the formula for has multiple date columns requiring this calculation and I don't want to use a helper column for each calculation. The array formula worked well, thank you.

Comment: you're welcome. Glad to help

Comment: @pnuts sure, thanks for the reminder ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A - Helper column**

The simplest approach for any scenario requiring working out on a row by row basis whether to do something or other - be it a sum, Lookup, etc - , is to use a 'helper' column alongside your data that uses a formula to work out whether it should or should not be included, typically returning 'True' if to be included.

With your data layout, in column D add a calculation that works out the difference and therefore whether the row should be included, such as:

`=C2-B2` or `=C2>B2` dragged down

The SUMIFS calc then becomes `=SUMIFS(A2:A11,D2:D11,">0")` or, for the general case with more complex criteria, `=SUMIFS(A2:A11,D2:D11,TRUE)`

This approach is excellent if you have a large number of complex criteria, perhaps varying by rows or perhaps requiring multiple `AND()` `OR()` and other logical evaluations (is a product ID x and is a customer ID y and is the value > z and is the days between purchase order being submitted and goods received more than 30 days) etc, to determine whether a row should be included in some further function.

**Option B - Array formula**

Alternatively, you can avoid the need for a working column by using an array formula that performs the comparisons in the formula. Under the data above this would be like:

`=SUM(IF(B2:B11<C2:C11,A2:A11,0))` entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>